# How to change a footnote to the first column using MDPI latex template

Tags: footnotes, paracol, mdpi

I used MDPI latex template.

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mdpi-article-template/fcpwsspfzsph

This template used the paracol package to divide the body text into two columns.
But the width of the two columns are different.
This position is to write the copyright on the first page.
However, from the next page, it will always be empty and inefficiently occupy a lot of space.

So I want to write a foot note in the first column. What should I do?

[image]

This image is original layout.

And I want to change it like this.

[image]

here is some definition from MDPI template (name is mdpi.cls)

```
%%%% Footnotes
\RequirePackage{scrextend}
\setlength{\skip\footins}{0.5cm} % Increase space between text and footnote
\setlength{\footnotesep}{5pt} % Increase space between line and footnote
%\deffootnote{1em}{0em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}\quad} % Remove indent
\deffootnote[1em]{5em}{1em}{%
   \textsuperscript{\tiny \thefootnotemark}%
}
\renewcommand{\pcol@footnoterule}{% Kerns avoid vertical space
  \kern -3pt                         % This -3 is negative
  \hrule width .3\textwidth height 0.4pt % of the sum of this 1
  \kern 2pt}                         % and this 2
\footnotelayout{m} % At the end of the page, not at the end of the column
```

How to change a footnote to the first column  ???

Comment: Have you explored the footmisc package with the option "side"?
https://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf

Comment: There are packages `snotez` and `sidenotes` for notes that should be written in the margin.